# What is the logic of comment @user autocomplete on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, comments, users, autocomplete

When I try to leave a comment to someone by pinging the user with his name (`@user_name` for example) I notice that sometimes the system doesn't help with autocomplete functionality:

> [image]

So I have to write the user's name manually, but I don't know if it will work and ping the mentioned user. But in the most of cases it works fine:

> [image]

**I wonder, if I can find out the logic of the @user autocomplete and how it works? And if I write the user's name manually if it will work correctly and ping the identified user?**

Comment: it only autocompletes for users that have responded to that post (these are the users that would be interested in being notified)

Comment: Downvote is prob for lack of research - [cross site dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/298072). Found by searching for "metastackoverflow tag users"

Comment: I always hate that autocomplete thing/feature. It would be nice if it was like twitter, and it was a real autocomplete, not a "i'll keep showing you the name as long as you're typing it right."